# Fill a PDF form with default data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, pdftk

I am working on  editing a `PDF` form/template  in **Ruby On Rails** application.
I want to populate some of form fields with data from database  and make few fields editable to take the input from user.
I found `PDFtf`  but I read that this is very old library and hardly works with the new Linux/Mac versions.
I checked https://www.adamalbrecht.com/blog/2014/01/31/pre-filling-pdf-form-templates-in-ruby-on-rails-with-pdftk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form fields are in FDF/XFDF files (very similar to a PDF as they are the data overlay) they are old hat but in constant use daily the library you link to is maintained this year and last stable release was [October 2020](https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms/releases/tag/1.3.0) it is the old proprietary Adobe Forms methodology that is very much stable since turn of the century.

see https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms#fdfxfdf-creation for how it uses PDFtk to adjust the FDFs

It does not matter which language or library you use the data is best kept static . I can write PDF via cmd so i guess fdf as text or xfdf as xml is just as easy.

best kept in simpler FDF format since for users its easiest to use a PDF/FDF reader / forms modifier such as Acrobat, Tracker or Foxit etc.

You can use any of those API s or just as simply use a find and replace method but its easiest to use a paid tool like PDFTK that can resolve the backgound mathematics. $79 for your server version will pay for itself quickly. Even $3 for a personal pro version is a bargain.

For a **Ruby specific** method using PDFtk last updated 28 Dec 2021 see https://github.com/ruby-journal/nguyen